# Laravel, JS socket client and 3rd party WS server

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a legacy website that's using pure PHP (no framework!), JS (no framework) and CSS.

It has a JS implementation of web socket client that's connected to a Java web socket server and communicate with it. When JS web socket client receives a command, it basically sends ajax request that either replaces current phtml file that's visible or just store some variable to PHP session.

Something like this:

```
Java WS server --> JS ws client --(ajax)> PHP store variable and return required phtml file --(ajax)> JS replace central panel with phtml from response.
```

It all sounds messy, yes, and i want to actually rewrite that website into Laravel, AlpineJS and Tailwind. The problem is, i'm not an expert with Laravel, and frankly from entire Laravel i just wanna use Blade flexibility and maybe some server-side variable storage as (for now) i would like to keep existing flow described above, just get away from pure php.

As my website revolves around JS web socket client that tells PHP what to do (using ajax) and which page to display ("display" mean PHP loads a phtml file that JS uses to dynamically replace central panel) I'm also not sure if i can have a pure JS web socket client, that can force laravel to change displayed blade components without page reloads.

Is even Laravel good solution for something like this or an overkill?